# Cassandra schema model organization

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

How to prepare schema with Cassandra

```
prepared a avia model schema for test.
Ticket(uuid: Long, flyCompany: FlyCompany, sitNumber: Int, user: User, date: String, ... )

User(uuid: Long, firstName: String, lastName: String, ... )
```

1. Thickets, Users, and so on.
2. Should I use id with auto increment like a relational database? Please provide reasons.
3. Should I use CRUD mapping or prepare DAO by myself?

What are positive and negative sides ?

Answer (score 1):

> 1.Thickets, Users, and so on.

Explain how you want to query date, the model will come after

> 2. Should I use id with auto increment like relational database ? yes, no, why ?

No there is nothing such as sequence with Cassandra because it would require a lock and we hate locking in distributed database. Use random UUID generation instead. If you want an increasing value, use TimeUUID. Look at this helper class: https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/3.0/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/utils/UUIDs.java

> 3. Should I use CRUD mapping or prepare DAO by myself ? Could you please clarify about positive and negative sides ?

You can use both. Some people are more confortable with object mappers, others prefer crafting the queries manually themselves to have better control (at least that's what they believe). A matter of personal taste here.

Comment: `1.Thickets, Users, and so on.
Explain how you want to query date, the model will come after`
For example:
1. Count avaliable tickets on the specific date.
2. Get free seats on the specific date
according to the cassandta date format support 
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html

Going to store date in milliseconds 
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/timestamp_type_r.html
For executing queries into database.